# How to save state of Fragments in ViewPager when orientation changes

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have an application that Implements ActionBarSherlock, it's mainly composed of
ViewPager with different content of fragments (for each page), with ViewPager indicator.

Here is my onCreate Method of the Activity that extends SherlockFragmentActivity

```
// Assume that tabs,sources,types are string arrays e.g. tabs = ["tab1","tab2","tab3"]
// types = ["listview","listview","webview"]
// according to the type of each tab, the type of content of the fragment associated to that tab is determined (e.g. WebView or ListView)
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
super.setContentView(R.layout.main);

srcContext = getBaseContext();
srcActivity = SaudiActivity.this;

int selectPos = 0;


Intent sender = getIntent();

FragmentPagerAdapter mAdapter = new NewsListAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
pager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

TabPageIndicator indicator = (TabPageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    indicator.setViewPager(pager);
    pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(tabs.length);
    pager.setCurrentItem((tabs.length - 1));
    currentPosition = (tabs.length - 1);

    indicator.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            currentPosition = position;
            if ((type[position] == "listview" || type[position]
                    .equals("listview")) && loaded[position] == false) {
                loaded[position] = true;
                getNews(listViews[position], position);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
                int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }
    });

    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.logo);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

    Context ctx = getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext();

    SourcesAdapter adapter = new SourcesAdapter(ctx,
    R.layout.navigation_list_item, src_name, icons, src_value);

}
```

Here are my News List Adapter (that creates the fragments),

```
    public static class MyViewHolder {
    public TextView title;
    public ImageView icon;
}

class NewsListAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public NewsListAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return new NewsFragment(MyActivity.this, position);
    }

    // This is the number of pages -- 5
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabs.length;
    }

    // This is the title of the page that will apppear on the "tab"
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabs[position];
    }

}

public List<NewsItem> NewsItems;
```

Finally here's my NewsFragment:

```
public static class NewsFragment extends Fragment {

    private int position;

    public NewsFragment() {
    }

    public NewsFragment(Context ctx, int pos) {
        this.position = pos;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,

    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = null;
        if (type[position].equals("listview")) {
            // Put a ListView in the Fragment
        } else {
            // Put a WebView in the Fragment
        }
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Let the fragment handle it's state by overriding onSaveInstanceState and placing the necessary values into outState. Recover that state in onCreateView using savedInstanceState. Also I'm pretty sure that if you're using Actionbarsherlock fragments need to extend SherlockFragment rather than Fragment.